# browser feature detection error using (navigator.geoloction)

Tags: javascript, browser-feature-detection

I have written a script to check if my browser has features. The following script is producing an error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
            <title id="title"> code Issues </title>
    </head>

    <body>      
            //=================== testing the feature detection method by using geolocation =======================//
            function geosuccess(position)
            {
                var cords = position.cords;
                var latitude = position.latitude;
                var longitude = postion.longitude;

                var message = "You're at " + latitude + ", " + longitude

                    alert(message);
            }

            function geoError(errorObj)
            {
                alert(errorObj.message);
            }

            if(typeof navigator.geolocation != "undefined")
            {
                console.log("inside geolocation");
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("thos page uses Geolocation and your browser doesn't support it");
            }


            //=================== End of testing the feature detection method by using geolocation =======================//


            </script>


    <h1>List Publishers Ltd.</h1>
    <div class="book">
        <h2>Sprout.</h2>
        <p>A book by J. Daniel Bedford</p>
        <a href="#">Read now.</a>
    </div>      
    </body>

</html>
```

If I run this I get an error that `geosuccess` is`undefined`.

I tried to debug the script and i can see it is not able to detect the function `geoSuccess(position)`.

I hope I am not missing an object oriented concept and the error is something related to the browser maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code lacks an opening `<script>` tag but I'll assume that's just a mistake.

Second, your code defines the function as `geosuccess` but you pass `geoSuccess` to `getCurrentPosition`. Please check wheter the cases match in your code.

Comment: you are totally right and i don't believe i am that blind, thanks a lot :)